# Distributed Recovery - can this be done without timeout?

Tags: distributed-computing, recovery, distributed-system, error-recovery

We have a mail sender application, that receives a bunch of mails in one blob, and then puts all those mails into database. This can take up to ten minutes. During this process the state of the mailing is `BUILDING`.

When it is finished the state gets changed to `READY`.

When the server crashes (shouldn't happen of course) and restarts, it looks for all mailings with status `BUILDING` and marks them as `ERROR`. This happens, because we never want to send incomplete mailings.

---

Now we'd like to scale up using a second server. The recovery strategy above doesn't work here.

e.g. server 1 is `BUILDING` a mailing, and server 2 crashes and restarts. Now server 2 will see the `BUILDING` mailing and doesn't know if it's been aborted or if it's running on another server.

---

So what's the best recovery strategy for distributed services?

*(We thought about some timeout mechanism, where the `BUILDING` server updates a timestamp every few seconds, and when some server reboots it checks if there's a `BUILDING` mailing that hasn't been updated for x minutes. Then it's highly possible that this mailing has been aborted.)*

---

### EDIT:

**What I'd like to achieve:** If some server restarts (after a crash or just because we added a new mailing server to the cluster), it should **not** mark mailings as `ERROR` if this particular mailing is actually being built (by another server).

**Nice to have:** If this would work without having to store server ids, because then it's possible to easily add and/or remove servers. Else it would not be possible to completely remove some server, because then there might be a `BUILDING` mailing with that particular server id. But this server got removed and will never get started again. Though the only server that could set the mailing to `ERROR` will be gone.

Comment: Can't you just track which server is building which mailing? So a crashed node knows which ones to mark as error.

Comment: @nodots:  By itself that would just stop servers from stepping on each others work.  Definitely necessary, but I don't see it as being sufficient.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Ah, I can see where you're coming from (full failover solution). I agree with your answer in that case. My interpretation of the question was narrower, in my comment I assumed that a failed node will eventually come back up and it would be ok to mark the error at that time.

Comment: @BenjaminM: Perhaps you could update your question, stating which recovery scenarios you'd like to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add two things to your state tracking:  a timestamp and the server working on it.

If a server starts up and sees anything in a building state for itself it knows it failed.  Conversely, if it starts up and sees something in a building state for another server, it now has information that it's going to need to look at later to see if there's a problem that needs to be addressed.  You need to worry about multiple servers restarting at the same time, so you can't just have a server grab all old bundles for all servers at startup.

Or you can just use a clustering service for your OS.

Comment: Is there also a possibility to achieve this without having to know about which server did what? I mean, I can't simply remove some server, because then there might be a server id in the log, which will never again exist. Then the mailing will never get set to `ERROR`.

Comment: Not really, if you want to have a setup where all servers are active in processing when they're running.  You have to have a way to stop each server from corrupting another server's work.  You do have to add some logic to detect when a server is down for a long enough time for another server to take over the work.  That can be prone to race conditions, though, if you have multiple servers trying to take over work.  Now, how reliable is your database?  There's no point in making your processing servers significantly more reliable than your database.

Comment: It's a MongoDB cluster with replication, though pretty reliable I'd say.

Comment: Do you need or want more than one processing server running at any one time?  If one processing server can handle your load and you just want multiple servers for availability, your best bet is probably using high-availability clustering to make sure one copy of your processing application is running somewhere on your set of processing servers.

Comment: No, I want multiple applications up and running. Mainly because of the `BUILDING` process. Most mails come to the server as template and then the server has to process that template 250000 times (for 250000 receivers) and fill in stuff like receiver.lastName, etc. or inline images. This takes 10 to 60 minutes. During this time the server is at 100% load.

Comment: If you want to omit tracking the processing node and periodically checking its health, you're basically back to a timeout mechanism like you described in your question. Actually, that _can_ be a minimum viable solution but introduces risk: You have to choose a timeout threshold that _no healthy workload will ever reach_. (In practice, replace _ever_ with _for now_. But you must remember that you _have_ a timeout and reassess its value periodically before it comes back to bite you. ;)

Comment: I could update the timestamp each time a mail has been generated and saved to database, this normally takes 20-100ms depending on the server load. Updating the timestamp would of course double the database queries, *but* **1.** I could do them unacknowledged (a fire and forget update of the timestamp), because it shouldn't matter if there's a failing update inbetween. **2.** I could update the timestamp only every 50 processed mails, which *should* happen at least every 5 seconds. So having a timeout of 1 minute should definitely show up errors. What do you think?

Comment: Sounds reasonable, Although I'd probably say a 5 or 10 min timeout would be better.  What problems are caused by restarting a job 10 minutes or so later compared to the problems caused by two servers doing the same work in parallel?  It's a tradeoff.  I'm admittedly more biased towards avoiding making things worse.